# Remove rows if a certain condition occur

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm dealing with a massive dataset. Let me make an example

```
df=data.frame(country = c("France","France","France","France","Italy","Italy","Italy","Italy","Spain","Spain","Spain","Spain"),year=c(replicate(3,c(2000,2001,2002,2003))),X=c(seq(1:12)))
```

I'd remove all the rows associated with a given country if (according to this example) X > 7 in 2002. As a result, Spain shall disappear

Comment: Something like `df[!with(df, country == 'Spain' & year == 2002), ]` ?

Comment: I don't know ex-ante which country has an X value above 7. The one above is just an example, I have thousands of entries in my dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take help of `match` to keep those countries whose value of `X` is less than equal to 7 in the year 2002.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(X[match(2002, year)] <= 7, .by = country)

#  country year X
#1  France 2000 1
#2  France 2001 2
#3  France 2002 3
#4  France 2003 4
#5   Italy 2000 5
#6   Italy 2001 6
#7   Italy 2002 7
#8   Italy 2003 8
```

Comment: I get the following error: Error in `filter()`:
! We detected a named input.
i This usually means that you've used `=` instead of `==`.
i Did you mean `.by == country`?

Comment: I think you may need to update `dplyr` version to above `1.1.0` or use the old way `df %>% group_by(country) %>% filter(X[match(2002, year)] <= 7)`

Answer (score 0):

```
%let pgm =utl-select-groups-of-rows-having-a-compound-condition-and-further-subset-using-wps-r-python-sql;

Select groups of rows having a compound condition and further subset using wps r python sql

github
https://github.com/rogerjdeangelis/utl-select-groups-of-rows-having-a-compound-condition-and-further-subset-using-wps-r-python-sql

  Solutions

     1 wps sql
     2 wps r sql
     3 wps python sql

I could not get any of the posted R solutions to work.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76876788/remove-rows-if-a-certain-condition-occur

/*                   _
(_)_ __  _ __  _   _| |_
| | `_ \| `_ \| | | | __|
| | | | | |_) | |_| | |_
|_|_| |_| .__/ \__,_|\__|
        |_|
*/

libname sd1 "d:/sd1";

data sd1.have;informat
COUNTRY $6.
YEAR 8.
X 8.
;input
COUNTRY YEAR X;
cards4;
France 2000 1
France 2001 2
France 2002 3
France 2003 4
Italy 2000 5
Italy 2001 6
Italy 2002 7
Italy 2003 8
Spain 2000 9
Spain 2001 10
Spain 2002 11
Spain 2003 12
;;;;
run;quit;

/**************************************************************************************************************************/
/*                               |                                        |                                               */
/*                               |                                        |                                               */
/* SD1.HAVE total obs=12         |  PROCESS                               | OUTPUT                                        */
/*                               |                                        |                                               */
/* bs    COUNTRY    YEAR     X   |                                        |   COUNTRY      YEAR         X                 */
/*                               |                                        |   ---------------------------                 */
/*  1    France     2000     1   |  After removing Spain                  |   France       2000         1                 */
/*  2    France     2001     2   |                                        |   France       2001         2                 */
/*  3    France     2002     3   |  select rows that are not              |   France       2002         3 Has 2002 x<=7   */
/*  4    France     2003     4   |                                        |   France       2003         4                 */
/*                               |  not (X > 7 and  year = 2002)          |                                               */
/*  5    Italy      2000     5   |                                        |   Italy        2000         5                 */
/*  6    Italy      2001     6   |                                        |   Italy        2001         6                 */
/*  7    Italy      2002     7   |                                        |   Italy        2002         7  Has 2002 x<=7  */
/*  8    Italy      2003     8   |                                        |   Italy        2003         8                 */
/*                               |                                        |                                               */
/*  9    Spain      2000     9   |  Remove SPAIN because it does not have |   Keep X=8 because NOT 2002 and x > 7.        */
/* 10    Spain      2001    10   |                                        |   2003 is enough to decide                    */
/* 11    Spain      2002    11   |  zt lease one ( year = 2002 and x<=7)  |                                               */
/* 12    Spain      2003    12   |                                        |                                               */
/*                               |                                        |                                               */
/**************************************************************************************************************************/

/*                                  _
/ | __      ___ __  ___   ___  __ _| |
| | \ \ /\ / / `_ \/ __| / __|/ _` | |
| |  \ V  V /| |_) \__ \ \__ \ (_| | |
|_|   \_/\_/ | .__/|___/ |___/\__, |_|
             |_|                 |_|
*/
proc datasets lib=sd1 nolist nodetails;delete want; run;quit;

%utl_submit_wps64x('

libname sd1 "d:/sd1";

options validvarname=any;

proc sql;
  create
     table sd1.want as
  select
     l.country
    ,l.year
    ,l.x
  from
    sd1.have as l, (
      select
         country
      from
         sd1.have
      having
        ( year = 2002 and x<=7)
      ) as r
  where
          l.country = r.country
      and not ( l.year = 2002 and l.x > 7)
;quit;
proc print data=sd1.want;
run;quit;

');

/*           _               _
  ___  _   _| |_ _ __  _   _| |_
 / _ \| | | | __| `_ \| | | | __|
| (_) | |_| | |_| |_) | |_| | |_
 \___/ \__,_|\__| .__/ \__,_|\__|
                |_|
*/

/**************************************************************************************************************************/
/*                               |                                                                                        */
/* The WPS System                |  The inn select results in                                                             */
/*                               |                                                                                        */
/* Obs    COUNTRY    YEAR    X   |   COUNTRY                                                                              */
/*                               |                                                                                        */
/*  1     France     2003    4   |   France                                                                               */
/*  2     France     2002    3   |   Italy                                                                                */
/*  3     France     2001    2   |                                                                                        */
/*  4     France     2000    1   |   Spain is dropped  because it does not have at least one                              */
/*                               |                                                                                        */
/*  5     Italy      2003    8   |   year = 2002 and x<=7                                                                 */
/*  6     Italy      2002    7   |                                                                                        */
/*  7     Italy      2001    6   |   The outer select just does the final filtering                                       */
/*  8     Italy      2000    5   |                                                                                        */
/*                               |                                                                                        */
/**************************************************************************************************************************/

/*___                                          _
|___ \  __      ___ __  ___   _ __   ___  __ _| |
  __) | \ \ /\ / / `_ \/ __| | `__| / __|/ _` | |
 / __/   \ V  V /| |_) \__ \ | |    \__ \ (_| | |
|_____|   \_/\_/ | .__/|___/ |_|    |___/\__, |_|
                 |_|                        |_|
*/

proc datasets lib=sd1 nolist nodetails;delete want; run;quit;

%utl_submit_wps64x('

libname sd1 "d:/sd1";

proc r;
export data=sd1.have r=have;
submit;
library(sqldf);
want <- sqldf("
  select
     l.country
    ,l.year
    ,l.x
  from
    have as l, (
      select
         max(country) as country
      from
         have
      group
         by country
      having
        max( year = 2002 and x<=7)
      ) as r
  where
          l.country = r.country
      and  ( l.year = 2002 and l.x > 7) = 0
  ");
want;
endsubmit;
run;quit;
');


/*____                                    _   _                             _
|___ /  __      ___ __  ___   _ __  _   _| |_| |__   ___  _ __    ___  __ _| |
  |_ \  \ \ /\ / / `_ \/ __| | `_ \| | | | __| `_ \ / _ \| `_ \  / __|/ _` | |
 ___) |  \ V  V /| |_) \__ \ | |_) | |_| | |_| | | | (_) | | | | \__ \ (_| | |
|____/    \_/\_/ | .__/|___/ | .__/ \__, |\__|_| |_|\___/|_| |_| |___/\__, |_|
                 |_|         |_|    |___/                                |_|
*/

%utl_submit_wps64x('

libname sd1 "d:/sd1";
proc datasets lib=sd1 nolist nodetails;delete want; run;quit;

proc python;
export data=sd1.have python=have;
submit;
 from os import path;
 import pandas as pd;
 import numpy as np;
 import pandas as pd;
 from pandasql import sqldf;
 mysql = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals());
 from pandasql import PandaSQL;
 pdsql = PandaSQL(persist=True);
 sqlite3conn = next(pdsql.conn.gen).connection.connection;
 sqlite3conn.enable_load_extension(True);
 sqlite3conn.load_extension("c:/temp/libsqlitefunctions.dll");
 mysql = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals());
 want=pdsql("""
  select
     l.country
    ,l.year
    ,l.x
  from
    have as l, (
      select
         max(country) as country
      from
         have
      group
         by country
      having
        max( year = 2002 and x<=7) = 1
      ) as r
  where
          l.country = r.country
      and  ( l.year = 2002 and l.x > 7) = 0
 """);
print(want);
endsubmit;
import data=sd1.want python=want;
run;quit;
proc print data=sd1.want;
run;quit;
');

/*              _
  ___ _ __   __| |
 / _ \ `_ \ / _` |
|  __/ | | | (_| |
 \___|_| |_|\__,_|

*/
```